# Gradle: Resources merging priority (Android)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We want to split our code base into several android library modules. One of them contains common-shared resources (strings, drawables, etc).

The problem arises when one of those resources, let's say `app_name`, is also defined in another external library. In that case, when all modules are merged, the resource with the id `app_name` is selected from an external library (randomly?), discarding the resource defined in our own local library module.

Is there a way to set a priority when merging resources to favour an specific library, or at least a module defined locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced off with this problem in the past and this is how I resolved it:

In your `app` module (your main module) adds this to the `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        '../my-module/src/main/res',
                        'src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}
```

- `../my-module/src/main/res` -> In this way your are referencing to the resources stored in the relative path to your library module (`my-module`)
- `src/main/res` -> Needed to reference to other resources that you have in your `app` module

### Android doc:

- Change your resource directory -> https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#change_your_resource_directory
- Resource merging -> https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#resource_merging

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2022;

Local libraries should already have priority over third-party ones,
but to prioritize a local-library over another local-library, simply change your include order.

Open your `settings.gradle` file, and ensure to include by order of what you want to have priority over others, like:

```
include ':app' // Heighest priority.
include ':my-library'
include ':my-other-lib' // Lowest priority.
```